# Why do For[] loop variables in different functions interfere?

Tags: variable

I had something along the lines of:

```
Func1[x_]:=(For[i=1,i<somenum,i++,
        Func2 [ x[[i]] ]
];)

Func2[a_]:=(For[i=1,i<anothernum,i++,
               Print[ToString[i]] ];)
```

And found that the i from the loop in Func1[] was being incremented by the loop in Func2[]. This was really surprising to me: I assumed, being local variables for defined at different points in the stack, they wouldn't know about each other. Changing the i in Func1[] to k fixed everything.

Is this usual/normal?

Comment: i is not local variables.The color of i is blue,which means global variables.Maybe you need learn about Module.

Answer (score 3):

Because `i` here is a global variable.  This is one of the reasons why I always suggest to beginners *never to use `For` loops*.

If you translate procedural code from other languages, use [`Do`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Do.html) instead.

There are very few cases in Mathematica when `For` is the best solution.  When you get more experienced, you'll be able to make that decision.  Until then it is really the best approach to pretend that `For` doesn't exist in Mathematica.

---

You can use [`Module`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Module.html) to localize variables.

Comment: Ah... is it because in a For[], I'm defining i when do i=1, but in a Do[], it's local because it's all in the {i,imin,imax}? Thanks!

Comment: @YungHummmma You can always localize `i` explicitly using `Module`.  But that's more complicated than just using `Do`, which does auto-localize.  Also, `Do` is more readable (because it's much shorter, and doesn't force one to look for commas and semicolons). Once you're using do, it's often just one step to switch to `Table` instead and get rid of the procedural code for good.

Comment: Hm, `Do[something[i],{i,i1,i2}]` indeed looks much cleaner than `Module[{i},For[i=i1,i<=i2,++i, something[i]]]`.